# sObject type 'PushTopic' is not supported - when creating object mapping in Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

When I try to create mapping for Contact object. When I select checkbox `Listen for updates using the Streaming API`, I get this error:

```
Unable to update mapping #bcc6b85b-42d4-4695-8be3-ea99112decd2. {"code":"badconfig","message":"PushTopic check failed: Server raised fault: 'INVALID_TYPE: \n FROM PushTopic\n ^\nERROR at Row:2:Column:22\nsObject type 'PushTopic' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'"}. Status code: 400 (HTTPError: error)
```

I got response on freenode#salsesforce:

> That type of error usually means an old API version that the new
>   standard object doesn't exist under

Also when I try to select checkbox `Write to Salesforce any updates to your database.`, I got error:

> Error:Read-write mappings require an upsert field for syncing. Upsert fields must be defined as unique External ID fields in Salesforce.More 
>   Warning:Fields needed for insertion to Salesforce need to be mapped: LastName

It was working 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Changing plan to higher than Professional solved the first issue with `Streaming API`.